# SQL referrals view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with users:

```
id              referred_by_user_id
-----------------------------------
1               null
2               1
3               1
4               2
```

I need to write request to get number of people referred by user in two levels.

- First - direct referral (example: user 1 referred users 2 3. count for level 1 = 2)
- Second - user 1 referred to users 2 and 3, user 2 referred to user 4. So count for level 2 should be 1

Result of query should be:

```
id              referred_user_tier_one_total      referred_user_tier_two_total
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               2                                 1 
2               1                                 null
3               null                              null 
4               null                              null
```

I figured out how to count referred_user_tier_one_total:

```
select 
    "id", referred_user_tier_one_total
from 
    "user"
inner join 
    (select 
         count(*) as referred_user_tier_one_total, referred_by_user_id
     from 
         "user"
     where 
         "user".referred_by_user_id is not null
     group by 
         "user".referred_by_user_id) ur on "user".id = ur.referred_by_user_id
```

But I don't understand how to calculate `referred_user_tier_two_total`. Please, help

**UPD:**

Thanks @Stoff for SQL Server solution.

Here is the script rewritten for Postgres

```
WITH RECURSIVE agg AS 
(
    SELECT
        a.ID, a.referred_by_user_id, 
        COUNT(b.referred_by_user_id) AS "count"
    FROM
        "user" a
    LEFT JOIN
        "user" b ON a.ID = b.referred_by_user_id
    GROUP BY 
        a.ID, a.referred_by_user_id
)
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    a.Count AS referred_user_tier_one_total, 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(b.count) IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE SUM(b.count) 
    END AS referred_user_tier_two_total 
FROM
    agg a
LEFT JOIN
    agg b ON a.ID = b.referred_by_user_id
GROUP BY
    a.ID, a.Count
ORDER BY 
    a.ID
```

Comment: Just an heads up, if you're going to include tier_one_total in tier_two_total, don't suggest in the name that it's ONLY tier_two_total. Took me a while to follow what you where trying to do here. Will take a look at it.

Comment: @Stoff oh sorry, my mistake. referred_user_tier_two_total is should the next only for level 2

Comment: I started writing this code in SSMS - which is not postgres. I'll give you a way of doing it in this syntax, sadly, I don't do postgres. Here you have it, should give you some idea of what you can do. Also, my code changes from NULL to 0: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=495787c1ed278ec2cd525f4b97bdaf7d

Comment: For the record, I know this is the wrong syntax. I simply did not see that it was postgres, and figured you might be able to use parts of what I did anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which works in Postgres.
We could carry on writing more levels in the same way.

> ```
> create table referals(
> id int,
> referred_by_user_id int);
> insert into referals values
> (1 ,         null),
> (2 ,            1),
> (3 ,            1),
> (4 ,            2 );
> ```

> ```
> select
> t0.id,
> count(t1.id) tier1,
> count(t2.id) tier2
> from
> referals t0
> left join referals t1
> on t0.id = t1.referred_by_user_id
> left join referals t2
> on t1.id = t2.referred_by_user_id
> group by t0.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | tier1 | tier2
> -: | ----: | ----:
>  1 |     2 |     1
>  2 |     1 |     0
>  3 |     0 |     0
>  4 |     0 |     0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b0ae3e84b9fc0ff572a32e5d8dc6989d)*